# Protractor test redirect

Tags: angular, testing, protractor

I've got an Angular application which I want to test. It has login section and I need to know somehow whether it worked fine (it sent login data, opened a socket connection, redirected to the apps depth and a route guard didn't prevent that redirection).

I've tried

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { browser, by, element, until } from "protractor";
import urlContains = until.urlContains;
```

...

```
it('should log in', () => {
        page.navigateTo();
        page.fillInputs();
        page.logIn();

        browser.waitForAngular();
        browser.wait(() => {
            return urlContains('dashboard');
        }, 2000);
    });
```

And it succeeds even if I do fill field with incorrect data and the app doesn't do any redirects. How do I achieve this redirect await and then checking the url?

I'm using Angular 6 if it's important.

Yes, I've seen a similar topic with answer that I don't understand.

Comment: Please show all the relevant code, for example, what does the method `urlContains` have?

Comment: @AshishRanjan it's an import check it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems I may have an old version of protractor, I could not find `urlContains` method the `until` namespace. I work with [ExpectedConditions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.urlContains) and it works fine for me.

So using Expected Conditions, you can have a code like:

```
expect(
  browser.wait(
    protractor.ExpectedConditions.urlContains("dashboard"), 5000
  )
    .catch(() => {return false})
).toBeTruthy(`Url match could not succced`);
```

I like using a catch so that the script doesn't stop in between whenever an error comes. Also an `expect()` will mark one test case(useful in reading generated reports).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way to detect "navigation end"? I also want to gather all items from menu and walk through them to make sure every "tab" is working as expected.

Comment: @Sergey: Protractor has no knowledge of angular objects. But if you have not disabled angular wait and using protractor commands (**not selenium commands** ) then protractor will automatically wait for navigation to complete before proceeding with next task in its queue